# Under what circumstances should I file form 1040 Schedule SE if I have an S Corporation?

Tags: united-states, s-corporation, form-1040

I'm reading conflicting information across the web regarding self-employment taxes on S Corps - some saying that S Corp shareholders (owners) are not considered self-employed, while others say S Corp shareholders file Schedule SE based on the 1120S Schedule K1 for distributions. In short, do I as a shareholder of my own S Corp need to file a Schedule SE with my individual 1040?

This is the confusing / self-contradicting article:
https://www.thebalance.com/self-employment-tax-and-fica-tax-explained-399037

Another self-contradicting article:
https://www.thebalance.com/schedule-c-or-schedule-k-tax-returns-397695

In this second article, they state "If you are the owner of a corporation or S corporation,  you aren't considered to be self-employed." Then they go on to say "... self-employment tax ... from S corp income on Schedule K-1"

Comment: Do you have self-employment income, or is it all from the S-Corp? Also, can you link a resource that suggests you'd file Schedule SE?

Comment: @HartCO it's all from the S-Corp